# Rounded Edges on UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

i'm currently working on a Plot Method to plot simple coords on a UIView.

I got my values in an array.

```
 foreach (int y in samples)
            {
                x += 10;
                path.AddLineTo(new PointF(x, baseline - y));
                pathDown.AddLineTo(new PointF(x, baseline + y));
            }
```

after that i set

```
path.ClosePath();
            pathDown.ClosePath();
            path.LineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round;
            path.LineJoinStyle = CGLineJoin.Round;
            pathDown.LineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round;
            pathDown.LineJoinStyle = CGLineJoin.Round;
            pathDown.Fill();
            path.Fill();
```

but the corners aren't rounded. What can i do?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` (from Objective-C, but there must be something equivalent in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already a method that should cover this for you: [`UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect%28System.Drawing.RectangleF%2CMonoTouch.UIKit.UIRectCorner%2CSystem.Drawing.SizeF%29)